# Using YouTubeVideoPlayer with Monogame

Tags: xamarin.android, android-mediaplayer, monogame

I'm currently trying to integrate a video player into my monodroid application. Wondering if there are any helpful solutions to this issue. Unable to load the player into the application (seems that multiple SurfaceViews can't be loaded at the same time). I'm currently trying to hide the monogame window by setting it invisible, and then adding the player to a containing FrameLayout. It seems after getting the player to display correctly, I'm unable to recover the game window, and I'm left with a blank screen (Even after removing all manually loaded textures from the application, I'm still not able to get anything to render! [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162552/on-xna-to-mono-android-conversions-what-is-a-simple-or-the-simplest-way-of-ha)).

I'd like to know if anyone's found a successful solution to incorporating the MediaPlayer into monogame?

Answer (score 0):

Not for youtube but, in the monogame samples there is a video player project. It was building and running for me but not showing the video on the emulator,  I couldn't test with a real device https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples/tree/master/VideoPlayer

To run the project you can go to https://github.com/CartBlanche/MonoGame-Samples/tree/master/ and open the MonoGame.Samples.Android.sln